# Set default terms for new posts / CPTs

Tags: filters, block-editor

I want to set default taxonomy hierarchical terms for NEW posts or CPTs. That is, I want the term's checkbox to default to checked - visually - in the **post-new.php** editor before it's saved or assigned an ID.I'm trying to use JS, but I'd prefer a PHP filter. Any clues?

I don't want to hook into publish or save, I want to have the check box pre-checked when **post-new.php** opens.

I'm trying to use JS, but I'd prefer a PHP filter. Any clues?

```
    wp_insert_term('Publish to Parler', 'parler',
        array(
            'slug'          => 'publish',
            'description'   => 'Publish a post to the Parler platform.',
        )
    );
```